# What happened to the blood hounds when Brienne attacked?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S6E1 of Game of Thrones:

> Blood hounds cornered Sansa and Theon. Brienne and Podrick attacked and defeated the Bolton soldiers. But what happened to the blood hounds?

Is this something that is covered in the book?

Comment: Related question from Movie.se [What happened to the dogs when Brienne came?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52198/what-happened-to-the-dogs-when-brienne-came) minus books.

Comment: They fell into a plothole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this meeting has not happened in the books as,

> **Brienne** is in Riverlands and has an "encounter" with another character who is not in the show. Her fate is unknown.

---

> **Sansa** is still in the Eyrie with Littlefinger.

---

To address your question about the hounds... We have a few options.

1. They were killed by Brienne and Podrick. This may be likely as the group is going to be on the run now. They would not want the dogs to return to the Boltons as they already know the scent.
2. They ran off after their masters were killed. Even though Theon says "You haven't seen what these hounds do to people", these were not likely "seek and destroy" hounds as a dead or severely injured Sansa is of no use to the Boltons and will actually lose them support in North (Roose was quick to point this out). I am no expert in hound training, but the hounds may or may not respond to another master. If that is the case they may be trained to return back to the kennels.
3. If the hounds will respond to another master, it is possible they will tag along with Sansa and company. However any proper inn along the King's Road is going to be dangerous. As grim as it may sound, they will probably be used for food!

Comment: I think the question was more about "where did the the hounds go during the fight?" As they just completely disappear while Brienne and Podrick are fighting! That seemed strange to me. Your point about them not being attack dogs is a good one perhaps, but they still seemed very menacing in the show.

Comment: True... they do just disappear.  The out-of-universe answer is then the scene would be to hard film.... as Ned Stark would say Brace yourself, plot holes are coming.